# AS3, getting XML data from external URL.

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, url

Im trying to work with this xml data :

http://flydata.avinor.no/XmlFeed.asp?TimeFrom=1&TimeTo=10&airport=KSU&direction=D%22

It contains all official flydata from an airport. I want to get the name of all airlines.

I get NULL no matter what i try. if i try to trace out the length of the  tag i get 0.

This is my code ;

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var myXML:XML = new XML();

 var XML_URL:String = "http://flydata.avinor.no/XmlFeed.asp?TimeFrom=1&TimeTo=10&airport=KSU&direction=D%22";


var re:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader(re);

ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

function loaded(e:Event):void{
myXML = XML(ldr.data);
trace("Succses");

}

var howLong:int = myXML.flight.length();

    for(var count:int=0; count < howLong; count++){
    var airline:String = myXML.flight[count].airline;



}
trace(airline)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `URLRequest` is an asynchronous operation so your `for` loop is executed before the XML has been loaded. You need to move the code which iterates over the returned XML into your complete handler:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var myXML:XML = new XML();
var XML_URL:String = "http://flydata.avinor.no/XmlFeed.asp?TimeFrom=1&TimeTo=10&airport=KSU&direction=D%22";


var re:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader(re);

ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

function loaded(e:Event):void {
    var howLong:int
    var airline:String;

    myXML = XML(ldr.data);
    howLong = myXML.flight.length();

    trace("Succses");

    for(var count:int=0; count < howLong; count++){
        airline = myXML.flight[count].airline;
        trace(airline);
    }
}
```